# Selenium enter date of birth (Python)

Tags: python, selenium

How do i enter my date of birth using selenium on discord? I tried it but i get following error:

```
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
(Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.128)
```

Code:

```
browser.get('https://discord.com/register')
time.sleep(5)

search_field=browser.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="app mount"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/form/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]''')

search_field.send_keys('March')
```

Comment: `//input[@aria-label='Month']`

Comment: thank you it is working. but it dissapears if i click something else